How to find the gradient when it equals to "$\frac00$"?

Find the gradient of the curve $C:ay^3+bx^2y+cxy=1$ where
$$cy+2bxy=0,\quad cx+bx^2+3ay^2=0,$$
if such a point exists.

If we try implicit differentiation, we get
$$3ay^2y'+2bxy+bx^2y'+cy+cxy'=0,$$
and so $y'=-\frac{2bxy+cy}{3ay^2+bx^2+cx}$. However, by the conditions, this expression is "$\frac00$". According to my experience in limits, we cannot just conclude that the gradient is $0$ or $\infty$.
So how to solve this problem correctly?

Have you determined whether such a point exists in the first place? Given three equations in two unknowns, it's hardly obvious that one exists.

I checked that such a point exists when $-432 a b^3+c^6=0$.

If you're working over the reals, then it appears based on plotting that said point is an acnode of $C$ under the condition you reference. In that case it's not at all evident that the gradient will in fact exist...

What do you mean by the gradient of a curve? We take the gradient of real valued functions on Euclidean space. Are you looking for the normal vector to the curve at certain points?

If the equation for the curve is $f(x,y) = 1$ then the two constraints imply that the point of interest is a critical point of the surface $z = f(x,y)$.  So you're looking a at a level curve of a surface that goes through a critical point.  If this point is a local minimum or maximum, the point is isolated (as @Semiclassical says).  If it's a saddle, it's a point where the curve self-intersects.  Either way, I can't see how a tangent vector will be defined.

One set of values satisfying the condition $-432ab^3+c^6=0$ is $(a,b,c)=(4,3,6)$.  This gives the curve $4y^3+3x^2y+6xy=1$. The equations $cy+2bxy=cx+bx^2+3ay^2=0$ become $(6+6x)y=6x+3x^2+12y^2=0$, which have the solutions $(x,y)=(0,0),(-2,0),(-1,\pm1/2)$. Of these, only $(-1,-1/2)$ is on the curve.

And $f(x,y)=4y^3+3x^2y+6xy\approx 1-\frac32 (x-1)^2-6(y+\frac12)^2$ near $(-1,-1/2)$ in the case indicated by @GerryMyerson, , so it's indeed an isolated point on the curve.

@messenger: There can be a tangent vector in cases where the Hessian is semidefinite, like the level curve through the origin for $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)^2$.

@HansLundmark sure - I don't think that can happen in the present example, however.
